# express-locale: allowed locales property not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, localization

I'm trying to use `express-locale` (v1.0.5) as middleware in my express app to determine locale from browser request.

I want to to match the found locale with a list of 'allowed' locales and fall back to default if the found one is not allowed.

`express-locale` is working fine and returning found locale. But when I specify 'allowed' property it just returns `undefined`.

I'm using it like this in my route:

```
import * as express from "express"
import { fetchLocalizationData, getLocale } from './localizationMiddleware'
const createLocaleMiddleware = require('express-locale')
const routes = express.Router()

/**
 *  Route to get localized strings for app
 *  @param {string} app: app name
 *  @param {string} lang: language to return
 *  @return {object}
 */
routes.get(
  "/localizations/:appId",
  // getLocale,
  createLocaleMiddleware({
    "priority": ["query","accept-language","cookie", "default"],
    "default": "da-dk",
    "allowed": ["da-dk", "en-gb", "sv-se"]
  }),
  fetchLocalizationData,
)

export default routes
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have version information? e.g. `package.json` (assuming you're using `npm`) ?

Comment: using version 1.0.5

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of **express-locale** up to at least 1.2.0 (including 1.0.5) require you to write locale configuration values using a fixed format with an underscore and uppercase region (e.g. `da_DK`).